# ¿Cómo vincular Excel a Google Sheets?

Tags: excel, google-apps-script, google-hoja-de-cálculo

Quería saber si es que se puede vincular datos de Microsoft Excel a Google Sheets.
por ejemplo

un usuario escribe en la celda A1 y a continuación aparezca en el A1 de Google Sheets.

¿Se puede hacer eso y cómo?

Comment: Deberias leer la documentación de las hojas de calculo de google, como dato te cuento que yo lo he trabajdo en la dirección contraria de hojas de calculo paso a excel

Comment: revisa esto por favor https://blog.sheetgo.com/how-to-solve-with-sheetgo/import-automatically-data-excel/

Comment: O sea si se puede pero es engorroso, la ganancia poca y el esfuerzo excesivo.

Answer (score 0):

Para escribir desde Excel a una hoja de cálculo de Google existen dos "API"s de Google que podrías usar

- [Google Sheets API](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/)
- [Google Apps Script API](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/api/)

Con la primera podrías hacer cambios directamente,  con la segunda podrías hacer cambios llamando funciones de algún proyecto de Google Apps Script.

Además con Google Apps Script podrías crear una aplicación web que acepte solicitudes GET / POST que a su vez estas llamen funciones de Google Apps Script.